# How to fetch record by month in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have stored Date in database in dd-mm-yy format, for example 03-10-2013,

How to search record by month? Month in digit (01 to 12);

I am using currently

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM data  WHERE date LIKE %$month%";
```

but this not working properly.

Comment: `.. WHERE MONTH(\`date\`) = $month`. Also I would not use `date` as a column name, it's kind of a reserved word or at least a function.

Comment: First of all you need to format database column to YYYY-mm-dd because DB understand only it

Comment: month without year may return data from all the year, also the data you are storing is not real date.

Comment: You also have a typo: WHRER <> WHERE!

Comment: if the `date` has an index then it's better to use calculated interval with `between` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix the date format in your database structure first, change it to: yyyy-mm-dd

Then change your query statement to:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE MONTH(`date`) = '$month';
```

This will select the month as '5' or '11' or '12' which will give duplicates for differing years.

If you need the month with year (to avoid duplicate years):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE SUBSTR(DATE(`date`),1,7) = SUBSTR(DATE('$month'),1,7);
```

This will return: '2015-01' or '2014-12'

To get date as '01' or '04' or '12':

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE SUBSTR(DATE(`date`),6,2) = SUBSTR(DATE('$month'),6,2);
```

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming when you say dates as stored in the database in a format, that they are not stored using a "date" type and instead are using a varchar or char type for the column.

Based on that there are few ways to do this.

1. Leave the database as it is and convert values on the fly.

`SELECT * FROM data WHERE Month(STR_TO_DATE(datestrcolumn, '%d/%m/%Y')) = 5;`

2. Change the type of the column to a "date" type column

`SELECT * FROM data WHERE Month(realdatecolumn) = 5;`

3. Change the type of the column to a "date" type column, store a separate column for the month.

`UPDATE data set monthcolumn = Month(realdatetimecolumn)`

then

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE monthcolumn = 5;
```

Create an index on monthcolumn and this query will be much faster than the other queries if there is a lot of data

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

You could use MySQL MONTH() function

MySQL MONTH() returns the MONTH for the date within a range of 1 to 12 ( January to December). It Returns 0 when MONTH part for the date is 0

4 is april

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE MONTH( date ) ='4'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like it... as it is not in date format(YYYY-MM-DD)

```
$q="SELECT * FROM data  WHERE MONTH(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d-%m-%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d') ) = '$YOUR_SEARCH_MONTH' ";
```